# What else, if anything, do we know about Delwin and Sand?

Tags: chronicles-of-amber, roger-zelazny

I can't remember whether it was in *[Knight of Shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_of_Shadows)* or *[Prince of Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Chaos)* but Merlin has an encounter, of sorts, with two Amberites who present something of a mystery. Merlin refers to them as "the legendary Delwin and Sand" and seem to know almost immediately who they are. There is no further mention of the two that I know of within Zelazny's *Amber* stories and unlike Tolkien Zelazny never released any huge appendices that I am aware of so the question is simple; apart from the fact that Merlin seems to know them, and consider them figures of some renown, what do we actually know about these two?

Information from Zelazny's writings only please, when it comes to understanding the *[Chronicles of Amber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)*, Betancourt's drivel is irrelevant in the worst way.

Comment: Briefly mentioned in Zelazny's *Visual Guide to Castle Amber*; https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqUv2.png

Comment: @Valorum could be there is an error in the guide

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - Dunno. I just spotted this when I googled the question title. I know nothing about this book series

Answer (score 1):

Blood of Amber:

Depicted on Luke's cards:

> **...another of a slim, russethaired man in brown and black, and one of
> a woman who resembled this man so closely it would seem they must be
> related.**
>
> «Okay. The lady,» he stated, «is Sand.» I stared so hard that I felt
> the beginnings of a contact. I smothered it.
>
> «The long-lost,» he
> added. I raised the card depicting the man who resembled her. «Then
> this must be Delwin,» I said. «Right.»
>
> ...But to confuse genealogists and sticklers for family legality, he had
> done it in a place where time flowed far more rapidly than in Amber.
> Interesting arguments both for and against the bigamous nature of his
> marriage to Harla may be made. I'm in no position to judge. **I had
> the story from Flora years ago, and in that she'd never gotten along
> too well with Delwin and Sand, the offspring of that union**, she was
> inclined to the pro-bigamy interpretation. I'd never seen pictures of
> Delwin or Sand until now. **There weren't any hanging around the
> palace, and they were seldom mentioned.** **But they had lived in
> Amber for the relatively short time Harla was queen there.** Following
> her death, they grew unhappy with Oberon's policies toward her
> homeland - which they visited often - and after a time they departed,
> vowing not to have anything to do with Amber again. At least that's
> the way I'd heard it. There could easily have been all sorts of
> sibling politicking involved, too. I don't know. But here were two
> missing members of the royal family, and obviously Luke had teamed of
> them and approached them, hoping to revive old resentments and gain
> allies. He admitted that it hadn't worked. Two centuries is a long
> time to hold a grudge at high pitch. That's about how long it had been
> since their departure, as I understood it.

Prince of Chaos:

> ...The frame was white, the glass was gray. Within
> was a man I had never met. **His shirt was black and opened at the neck.
> He wore a brown leather vest, his hair dark blond, eyes perhaps green.**
> «Yes?» «A spikard was hidden in Amber,» he stated, «for you to find.
> It conveys great powers. It also bears a series of spells that will
> cause its wearer to act in certain ways under certain circumstances.»
> «I suspected this,» I said. «What is it set to do?» «Formerly worn by
> Swayvill, King of Chaos, it will force the chosen successor to take
> the throne, behave in a certain fashion, and be amenable. to the
> suggestions of certain persons.» «These being?» «The woman who laughed
> and cried, `Seek him in the Pit. ' The man in black, who desires your
> return.» «Dara and Mandor. They laid these spells upon it?» «Just so.
> And the man left it for you to find.» «I hate to surrender the thing
> just now,» I said, «when it's proving so useful. Is there a way to
> lift these spells?» «Of course. But it should not matter to you.» «Why
> not?» «The ring you wear is not the one of which I speak.» «I do not
> understand.» «But you will. Never fear.» **«Who are you, sir?» «My name
> is Delwin, and we may never actually meet - unless certain ancient
> powers come loose.» He raised his hand, and I saw that he, too, wore a
> spikard**. He moved it toward me. «Touch your ring to mine,» he
> commanded. «Then it can be ordered to bring you to me.» I raised mine
> and moved it toward the glass. At the moment they seemed to touch,
> there was a flash of light and Delwin was gone.

The Salesmans' Tale:

> **"'Seek the guardians?'"** "There is a custodian--possibly two," she replied. "A self-exiled Prince of  Amber and his sister have guarded a
> portion of this power for a long while. It  would seem in order to see
> that they still live, still discharge the duty." "Self-exiled? Why?"
> "Personal reasons, involving the late King." "Where are they?" "I do
> not know." ...When she returned she presented me with the card,
> portrait of a slim man  with hair the color of rust. "His name is
> Delwin," she said. "You think I should just call him and ask whether
> he still has whatever he  had?"
>
> "Who is it?" I felt the question even before the likeness took on
> depth and  life. "Luke Reynard, otherwise known as Rinaldo," I
> answered, as the card was  suddenly animated and I felt his scrutiny,
> "King of Kashfa and B.S. in Business  Management, University of
> California at Berkeley." Our gazes locked. He seemed  neither
> belligerent nor friendly. **"I wanted to know whether your stewardship
> of  the spikards remains intact."**